# Schedule a Rscript crontab everyminute

Tags: r, terminal, cron

For some reason my R script will not run with a crontab. I have it for every minute right now for testing, but will change it once it works.

Any ideas?

```
* * * * * Rscript “/Users/Home/Desktop/David Studios/Scraper/compiler.R”
```

Also, this was working as just a normal command in Terminal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can see the dreaded [smart quotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark#Curved_quotes_and_Unicode) in your cron entry. This often happens when you copy-paste from word processors. Backspace over those abominations and re-type normal quotes. Change:

```
* * * * * Rscript “/Users/Home/Desktop/David Studios/Scraper/compiler.R”
```

to

```
* * * * * Rscript "/Users/Home/Desktop/David Studios/Scraper/compiler.R"
```

See the difference? It's subtle and easy to miss.

### Update:

I see you've made the above change and it's still not working for you. Verify that `Rscript` is in the `$PATH` environment variable for the user that owns this crontab. Alternatively, you can simply specify the fully qualified path to `Rscript` directly in the cron entry. You can find that quickly on the command line with the following command:

```
which Rscript
```

### Update #2:

I see by your comments that the fully qualified path to `Rscript` is `/usr/local/bin/Rscript`. I'm guessing `/usr/local/bin` is not in the path for the user who owns this crontab. Try using the fully qualified path, like this:

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/Rscript "/Users/Home/Desktop/David Studios/Scraper/compiler.R"
```

Comment: I've made that update, but still no dice.. any other ideas?

Comment: Is `Rscript` in the path for the user that owns this crontab? If you specify the fully qualified path to `Rscript`, does it work?

Comment: I think that's where I'm stuck. I've re-installed R but I don't think that worked. Is there a way to declare the path in the command?

Comment: it is  /usr/local/bin/Rscript

Comment: Ok, so try changing your crontab entry to `* * * * * /usr/local/bin/Rscript "/Users/Home/Desktop/David Studios/Scraper/compiler.R"`

Comment: Still nothing. Should I move this to chat?

Comment: @frameworkgeek, did you ever resolve this? I have the same issue.

Comment: So, in your script.R file, add #!/bin/bash    to the top of the script, then in your crontab write the following :
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/Rscript  /Users/path/to/file/script.R  (there is a space after Rscript)

then, run chmod +x script.R   in the folder where your script is located

Answer (score 3):

You might have a problem with the working directories in R.

When you run the script from the terminal you might be in the directory where the files the script needs are, but when the script runs with cron it uses another directory.

Use the setwd() function inside the R script or use absolute paths when accesing files to make sure the script works no matter where it is being used.

Comment: seems like a reasonable guess.  This three year old question is actually too broad to answer definitely - invites discussions and guesses from what I can tell.

Answer (score 2):

Check that you are really running crontab deamon. You should get a number as return, which is the process id for crontab.

```
pgrep cron
```

Make sure your R file is execuable:

```
sudo chmod +x [yourfile.R]
```

Add the shebang line in your R file:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/Rscript
```

Let crontab do the change of directory:

```
* * * * * cd /Users/Home/Desktop/David Studios/Scraper/ && /usr/local/bin/Rscript compiler.R
```

Answer (score 1):

I just spent several hours on a similar problem.  I'm still not completely sure what was wrong, but the following command finally worked and I don't really care why.  Hopefully this can help someone else.

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/Rscript -e 'source("/home/rstudio/git/myproject/inst/please_work.R")'
```