# Close and reopen + run an R script from itself on Mac

Tags: r

I would like to write an R script that can close and reopen + run itself.

This is needed for an API query that I am trying to make and which seems to require me going through these steps once every hour to be able to make additional requests. I tried to use the `source()` function - and simply run my script from itself every hour- but with this the API keeps rejecting additional requests; it seems that actually closing and opening the program is necessary.

I also tried to use the `system()` command - as described [here](http://datacornering.com/how-to-run-r-script-from-another-r-script-and-use-as-a-source/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20execute%20R%20script,the%20file%20path%20contains%20space) to actually open R and execute the script - but I was not able to figure out how to implement this in a Mac environment.

Would you have any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to run a script every x amount of time on a Unix system is a cronjob. I'm not familiar with macOS, but [apparently](https://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/schedule-jobs-with-crontab-on-mac-osx/) it works just as on Linux.

1. Open the job list to edit it (you can of course use another editor instead of nano)

```
env EDITOR=nano crontab -e
```

2. Add a line/job to the file. This runs any command line command. You can use [Rscript](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.6.2/topics/Rscript) to run an R script.

```
0 * * * * Rscript "/path/to/your/script.R"
```

3. Exit and safe. This script should now run every hour.

If you want to change the timing check out [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/every-1-hour). Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38778749/3216883), if the cronjob reports Rscript to be missing.